# how to change the size, color of points in a scatter plot in R

Tags: r

[You can find the example data in below](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cc92b75e17ea366898d4)[image]

I want to color, recognise those points higher than 0 in another color and lower than 0 in another color. Is there any way to know which points are they ? I simply want to add a border higher and lower -1 and then say show those point higher than 1 in another color and print their name close to it while the same for lower than -1 but another color

This comment did not help since make read line randomly

```
x=(1:990)
cl = 1*(z>0) + 2*(z<=0)
cx = 1*(z>0) + 1.2*(z<=0)
plot(y~x, col=cl, cex=cx)
```

[image]

I don't want to generate red and black points around zero.
I want to detect those points higher and lower than 1 and -1 respectively.
I also want to plot them in different color and different size

Comment: Take a look at this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17551193/r-color-scatter-plot-points-based-on-values?rq=1 especially the code in the question.

Comment: Hey Nemo. It helps if you can provide a sample dataset for people to help you with. Looks like the plot you've provided is from the base R packages. You need to install something with a little more versatility `install.packages("ggplot2")' and then you can certainly get to the type of output you're after. But in the first instance help us help you.

Comment: You can find an example data by clicking on the link above the figure

Comment: I tried that example you posted but it did not work for me that is why I posted my question here

Comment: then you should change 0 for whatever value you want in the code that I posted. I just changed to 0.1 and -0.1.

Comment: I did not mean to make you sad! simply read my question and if you can help me with exactly what I need, please comment, I will be happy to accept. I even posted a sample data, I don't need a simulated data !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate some data around 0:

```
d<-rnorm(1000,0,1)
```

To get the points higher than 0:

```
d[d>0]
```

To identify the index of points higher than 0:

```
which(d>0)
```

Plot points above 0 in green below 0 in red.  Also, points above 0 will be a different size than points below 0:

```
s <- character(length(d))
s[d>0] <- "green"
s[d<0] <- "red"
# s[d > -0.5 & d < 0.5] <- "black" # to color points between 0.5 and -0.5 black
plot(d, col=s)  # color effect only

sz <- numeric(length(d))
sz[d>0] <- 4  # I'm giving points greater than 0 a size of 4
sz[d<0] <- 1

plot(d, col=s, cex=sz)  # size and color effect
```

Now, you also mention points above and below 1 and -1, respectively.  You should be able to follow the code above to do what you want.

To add labels to points meeting a certain condition (e.g. greater than or less than 0.2 and -0.2, respectively), you can use the `text` function:

```
text(which(abs(d) > .2), d[abs(d) > .2], cex = 0.5, pos=3)
```

`pos = 3` means to put the label above the point, and the `cex` argument to text is for adjusting the label size.

Comment: slightly better to use `s <- character(length(d))`, `sz <- numeric(length(d))`

Comment: This is a very good comment, Thanks frank !!!! is it possible to also keep those zero or those values which is between (higher and lower) values in the figure for example by black color ??

Comment: Ben, if I use s <- character(length(d))  or sz <- numeric(length(d))  I get Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : invalid color name ''

Comment: Use @ in front of a username to respond to people (e.g. @Frank), or they may not notice.  See my answer to see how I incorporated Ben's comments.  To color points between 0.5 and -0.5 black add the following line `s[d > -0.5 & d < 0.5] <- "black"` after this line: `s[d<0] <- "red"`

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable comment @Frank

Comment: @Frank do you know how to add Label to specific scatter points for example those with higher values than 0.2 ( show their index) and those with lower than -0.2 (show their index) on plot

Comment: You can use the `text` function.  For example, `text(which(abs(d) > .2), d[abs(d) > .2], cex = 0.5, pos=3)`.  Change the `cex` argument to change the size.  `pos=3` means to put the label above the point.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments mentioned, there are many ways of doing this. Assuming that you are using the `plot()` function, here's a simple way of doing what you want. The key is to understand the arguments of `plot()`. Color of points is determined by `col`, size by `cex`, and so forth. These should all be vectors of the same size of `y` (else the recycling rule is used). See `?plot`.

```
N = 999 # I don't care how many obs you have
y = rnorm(N)

# vector of colors (black for y>0, red for y<=0)
cl = 1*(y>0) + 1.2*(y<=0)

# vector of point sizes relative to default (1 for y>0, 1.2 y<=0)
cx = 1*(y>0) + 1.2*(y<=0)  

plot(y, col=cl, cex=cx)
```

### Edit:

I tried to give a general example (eg, coloring points by a third variable), but OP insists he had 2 variables. Well, just rename `z` by say `x`.

### Edit:

```
# last edit I make
set.seed(1)
y = rnorm(N)
cl = rep(1, length(y))
cl[y > 0.5] = 2
cl[y < -0.5] = 3

plot(y, col=cl)
```

And here's what it gives:[image]

Comment: Please read my question, I posted my data above the figure.  I don't have three rows of data, I only have two rows, one is the data and one is 1:990 which shows we have 990 data point. what you show here is not helping me out

Comment: i tried to give a general answer that can be easily adapted to your case. that is, if you try to understand it. I'm helping, but not doing your homework for you.

Comment: there you go @Nemo. happy now?

Comment: It just make randomly red and black. I am looking to recognise my points higher than and lower than zero. please look at above , how your comment work

Comment: ok, you REALLY don't get this. I simulated some data. YOU can use whatever data YOU want. unbelievable. note to self: NEVER answer one of Nemo's question again.

Comment: I did not mean to make you sad! You just made something you liked . You even did not read my question properly ! Please read it first , look above what you posted here and compare to what I really wanted.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just voted for your comment but above he replied all the question I had in plotting my figure, Once again thanks @djas