# How to change the color of points in a specific quadrant?

Tags: r, plot

I have a scatter plot of data points, and I am able to use `abline` to create the quadrant lines. Now I'm trying to color the points of those in quadrant 1 and quadrant 3. I am going to plot all the points first, and then plot only those in quadrant one in red, and those in quadrant three in blue. They will be superimposed on the old ones. However, I don't know how to plot points by quadrant. Thank you.

"write the R code to plot the points that are in the(Q1,Q1) quadrant of(waiting, eruption) in Red, AND the points that are in the(Q3,Q3) Quadrant of(waiting, eruption) in blue, everything else in black, use a `pch=19` and `cex=0.5`. (Hint, plot everything with `pch=19, col="black"` first, then add the conditional points with the required colors, they will be superimposed on the old ones, whatever left stays in black)."

This is my foundation:

```
plot(faithful$waiting, faithful$eruptions, pch=19, cex=0.5, col="black")
```

[image: plot]

I realize I somehow need to plot only those in quadrant 1 in a color and then plot those in quadrant 3 in another color, and run that code after my foundation. But I'm not sure how. Thanks.

The `dput(faithful)` is:

```
structure(list(eruptions = c(3.6, 1.8, 3.333, 2.283, 4.533, 2.883, 
4.7, 3.6, 1.95, 4.35, 1.833, 3.917, 4.2, 1.75, 4.7, 2.167, 1.75, 
4.8, 1.6, 4.25, 1.8, 1.75, 3.45, 3.067, 4.533, 3.6, 1.967, 4.083, 
3.85, 4.433, 4.3, 4.467, 3.367, 4.033, 3.833, 2.017, 1.867, 4.833, 
1.833, 4.783, 4.35, 1.883, 4.567, 1.75, 4.533, 3.317, 3.833, 
2.1, 4.633, 2, 4.8, 4.716, 1.833, 4.833, 1.733, 4.883, 3.717, 
1.667, 4.567, 4.317, 2.233, 4.5, 1.75, 4.8, 1.817, 4.4, 4.167, 
4.7, 2.067, 4.7, 4.033, 1.967, 4.5, 4, 1.983, 5.067, 2.017, 4.567, 
3.883, 3.6, 4.133, 4.333, 4.1, 2.633, 4.067, 4.933, 3.95, 4.517, 
2.167, 4, 2.2, 4.333, 1.867, 4.817, 1.833, 4.3, 4.667, 3.75, 
1.867, 4.9, 2.483, 4.367, 2.1, 4.5, 4.05, 1.867, 4.7, 1.783, 
4.85, 3.683, 4.733, 2.3, 4.9, 4.417, 1.7, 4.633, 2.317, 4.6, 
1.817, 4.417, 2.617, 4.067, 4.25, 1.967, 4.6, 3.767, 1.917, 4.5, 
2.267, 4.65, 1.867, 4.167, 2.8, 4.333, 1.833, 4.383, 1.883, 4.933, 
2.033, 3.733, 4.233, 2.233, 4.533, 4.817, 4.333, 1.983, 4.633, 
2.017, 5.1, 1.8, 5.033, 4, 2.4, 4.6, 3.567, 4, 4.5, 4.083, 1.8, 
3.967, 2.2, 4.15, 2, 3.833, 3.5, 4.583, 2.367, 5, 1.933, 4.617, 
1.917, 2.083, 4.583, 3.333, 4.167, 4.333, 4.5, 2.417, 4, 4.167, 
1.883, 4.583, 4.25, 3.767, 2.033, 4.433, 4.083, 1.833, 4.417, 
2.183, 4.8, 1.833, 4.8, 4.1, 3.966, 4.233, 3.5, 4.366, 2.25, 
4.667, 2.1, 4.35, 4.133, 1.867, 4.6, 1.783, 4.367, 3.85, 1.933, 
4.5, 2.383, 4.7, 1.867, 3.833, 3.417, 4.233, 2.4, 4.8, 2, 4.15, 
1.867, 4.267, 1.75, 4.483, 4, 4.117, 4.083, 4.267, 3.917, 4.55, 
4.083, 2.417, 4.183, 2.217, 4.45, 1.883, 1.85, 4.283, 3.95, 2.333, 
4.15, 2.35, 4.933, 2.9, 4.583, 3.833, 2.083, 4.367, 2.133, 4.35, 
2.2, 4.45, 3.567, 4.5, 4.15, 3.817, 3.917, 4.45, 2, 4.283, 4.767, 
4.533, 1.85, 4.25, 1.983, 2.25, 4.75, 4.117, 2.15, 4.417, 1.817, 
4.467), waiting = c(79, 54, 74, 62, 85, 55, 88, 85, 51, 85, 54, 
84, 78, 47, 83, 52, 62, 84, 52, 79, 51, 47, 78, 69, 74, 83, 55, 
76, 78, 79, 73, 77, 66, 80, 74, 52, 48, 80, 59, 90, 80, 58, 84, 
58, 73, 83, 64, 53, 82, 59, 75, 90, 54, 80, 54, 83, 71, 64, 77, 
81, 59, 84, 48, 82, 60, 92, 78, 78, 65, 73, 82, 56, 79, 71, 62, 
76, 60, 78, 76, 83, 75, 82, 70, 65, 73, 88, 76, 80, 48, 86, 60, 
90, 50, 78, 63, 72, 84, 75, 51, 82, 62, 88, 49, 83, 81, 47, 84, 
52, 86, 81, 75, 59, 89, 79, 59, 81, 50, 85, 59, 87, 53, 69, 77, 
56, 88, 81, 45, 82, 55, 90, 45, 83, 56, 89, 46, 82, 51, 86, 53, 
79, 81, 60, 82, 77, 76, 59, 80, 49, 96, 53, 77, 77, 65, 81, 71, 
70, 81, 93, 53, 89, 45, 86, 58, 78, 66, 76, 63, 88, 52, 93, 49, 
57, 77, 68, 81, 81, 73, 50, 85, 74, 55, 77, 83, 83, 51, 78, 84, 
46, 83, 55, 81, 57, 76, 84, 77, 81, 87, 77, 51, 78, 60, 82, 91, 
53, 78, 46, 77, 84, 49, 83, 71, 80, 49, 75, 64, 76, 53, 94, 55, 
76, 50, 82, 54, 75, 78, 79, 78, 78, 70, 79, 70, 54, 86, 50, 90, 
54, 54, 77, 79, 64, 75, 47, 86, 63, 85, 82, 57, 82, 67, 74, 54, 
83, 73, 73, 88, 80, 71, 83, 56, 79, 78, 84, 58, 83, 43, 60, 75, 
81, 46, 90, 46, 74)), row.names = c(NA, 272L), class = "data.frame")
```

And how I defined my quadrants:

```
plot(faithful$waiting, faithful$eruptions, pch=19, cex=0.5, col="green")
abline(v=quantile(faithful$waiting, 0.75), col="red")
abline(h=quantile(faithful$eruptions,0.75),col="red")  
abline(v=quantile(faithful$waiting, 0.25), col="red")
abline(h=quantile(faithful$eruptions,0.25),col="red")  

mtext("Q1", side=1, at=quantile(faithful$waiting, 0.25), col="red")
mtext("Q1", side=2, at=quantile(faithful$eruptions, 0.25), col="red")
mtext("Q3", side=2, at=quantile(faithful$eruptions, 0.75), col="red")
mtext("Q3", side=1, at=quantile(faithful$waiting, 0.75), col="red")
```

What I've been trying, when using a grouping:

```
faithful$color<- 'black'

q1<-quantile(faithful$waiting, 0.25)  #how do I assign the quantiles
q3<-quantile(faithful$waiting, 0.75)

faithful$color[faithful$waiting  ]="red"    #how do I then assign the quantiles a color
faithful$color[faithful$waiting  ]="blue"
```

Comment: Maybe add a "grouping" showing which points belong to which quadrant and link the colours to that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R color scatter plot points based on values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17551193/r-color-scatter-plot-points-based-on-values)

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you make this more reproducible, share e.g. `dput(faithful))`.

Comment: @jay.sf just added dput. thank you.

Comment: How are you defining "quadrants" for this plot?

Comment: @G5W I was using abline and boxplots previously. I put the code above to show the quadrants I need to color. Thanks.

Comment: @NelsonGon Sorry, I tried to use the link and do a grouping. But I'm not sure how to group them by quartile and then assign color. I do: 
```faithful$color<- 'black'

q1<-quantile(faithful$waiting, 0.25)  #how do I assign the quantiles
q3<-quantile(faithful$waiting, 0.75)

faithful$color[faithful$waiting  ]="red"    #how do I then assign the quantiles a color
faithful$color[faithful$waiting  ]="blue"``` 
but I'm lost

Comment: You should define the "grouping" prior to plotting. It's easier to "just" select a column by which to colour than manually doing so for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `cut` both variables into quantiles and `paste` the levels together to obtain a group for each quadrant.

```
faithful <- within(faithful, {
  e.qtl <- as.integer(cut(faithful$eruptions, 
                          quantile(faithful$eruptions, c(0, .25, .75, 1)), 
                          include.lowest=TRUE))
  w.qtl <- as.integer(cut(faithful$waiting, 
                          quantile(faithful$waiting, c(0, .25, .75, 1)), 
                          include.lowest=TRUE))
  qtl <- as.integer(as.factor(with(faithful, 
                                   paste0(e.qtl, w.qtl))))
})
```

Then we can easily plot the data assigning `col`or for each group.

```
colors <- rainbow(length(unique(faithful$qtl)))  # create colors

# plot
plot(faithful$waiting, faithful$eruptions, type="n")  # empty plot here
with(faithful, points(waiting, eruptions, col=colors[qtl], pch=19, cex=0.5))
```

After that add your `abline`s and `mtext`.

```
abline(v=quantile(faithful$waiting, 0.75), col="red")
abline(h=quantile(faithful$eruptions, 0.75),col="red")  
abline(v=quantile(faithful$waiting, 0.25), col="red")
abline(h=quantile(faithful$eruptions, 0.25),col="red")  
mtext("Q1", side=1, at=quantile(faithful$waiting, 0.25), col="red")
mtext("Q1", side=2, at=quantile(faithful$eruptions, 0.25), col="red")
mtext("Q3", side=2, at=quantile(faithful$eruptions, 0.75), col="red")
mtext("Q3", side=1, at=quantile(faithful$waiting, 0.75), col="red")
```

#### Result

[image]