# How to assign the same colors to duplicate values using plot() function in R?

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataframe with 4 columns. I am plotting total car crashes vs. total losses colored by the column "distance". I am able to generate a colored plot. However when I inspect the plot I see the plot is not colored the way it is supposed to be. Since there are many duplicate distance values I created a palette by the unique values of the distance column. And then assigned this as color to legend and plot(). However examining plot colors are not right. For example distance 600 is colored with yellow in legend but the corresponding dot is colored red. I think the problem is that I need to create a color as much as the number of instances in the dataframe which is 58. But I have duplicate values and they are not originally sorted.Basically I need colors from lowest distance to highest distance with increasing shade of a color that will match with the crashes and losses data properly. 
Below is the minimum reproducible dataframe and my code that works but is flawed.

```r
# creating dataframe
year <- data.frame(year = seq(1946,2003,1))
crashes <- data.frame(crashes = c(386,317,294,287,266,245,268,296,226,265,243,239,183,212,195,224,170,169,140, 147,111,119,100,115,128,111,80,77,68,69,84,72,90,82,59,67,45,59,50,64,55,63,56,56,57,68,34,32,26,21,20,30,35,28  ,22,27,34,NA))
losses <- data.frame(losses = c(432,423,341,291,282,288,387,323,229,305,244,333,200,215,211,245,197,177,153,152, 115,189,124,129,133,120,91,90,69,78,88,77,95,98,62,70,45,62,70,68,65,73,90,65,61,74,39,33,31,22,21,39,35,58,25,36 ,40,NA))
distance <- data.frame(distance = c(600,571,589,613,618,605,605,610,608,584,605,615,605,597,603,600,578,560,541,500,478,459,449,447,452,444,431,433,452,436,426,425,430,426,430,417,372,401,389,418,414,397,443,436,431,439,430,425,415,423,437,463,487,505,503,508,516,529))
df <- cbind(year,crashes,losses,distance)
palette <- heat.colors(length(unique(df[order(df$distance),]$distance)))
plot(df$crashes,df$losses, main = "Crashes,Losses and Distance",xlab = "Crashes", ylab = "Losses", col = palette)
#legend
legend(x = 401,y = 450, legend = unique(df[order(df$distance),]$distance) , cex=.3, fill = palette, xpd=TRUE)
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17551193/r-color-scatter-plot-points-based-on-values. Your color vector needs to be the same length as your x and y vectors and should give the color for each point, not just a list of the colors you want to use.

Comment: @MrFlick I feel like for 58 values in total and 47 unique values manually filtering would take long

Comment: Well, it doesn’t have to a manual process. Are you sure you want to use base R? This would be easier with ggplot probably.

Comment: @MrFlick It would be better to use the  plot() function. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Hi from what i understand you are trying to give each distance a unique colour, this is very easy but i would highly recommend you to first add a grouping character factor for the distances, instead of using 47 unique levels of distance (the numerics > this would result in 47 different colours you can try it if you use: 'distance' instead of: 'distance_new' in the following)

here is my code for this:

```
# same df as you posted:
df <- cbind(year,crashes,losses,distance)

# this is necessary if you would want to use 'distance' for coloring
df$distance<- as.factor(df$distance) 

## imo better add a grouping factor distance_new 
## (this is automatically stored as class factor)

df$distance_new<-cut(as.numeric(df$distance),4, labels = c("very low","low","medium","high"))

# Now the plot
plot(df$crashes,df$losses, main = "Crashes,Losses and Distance",
xlab = "Crashes", ylab = "Losses",
col = df$distance_new, pch =19)

# add a legend
legend("bottomright",legend = unique(df$distance_new ),
fill=unique(df$distance_new), cex= 0.5, title= "Distance")
View(df)
```

[image]

Comment: This  works out in a different way than I asked for but how could it be done if I wanted to keep the distance values and not group them into categories?

Comment: it works the same , just use: 'distance' (has to be a factor) ,  instead of: 'distance_new'